# Pretty print ByteString to hex nibble-wise

Tags: haskell, hex, pretty-print, bytestring

What's an idiomatic way of treating a bytestring nibblewise and pretty printing its hexadecimal (0-F) representation?

```
putStrLn . show . B.unpack
-- [1,126]
```

Which, upon further work

```
putStrLn . show . map (\x -> N.showIntAtBase 16 (DC.intToDigit) x "") . B.unpack
["1","7e"]
```

But what I really want is

```
["1","7","e"]
```

Or better yet

```
['1','7','e']
```

I could munge up ["1","7e"] but that string manipulation whereas I'd rather do numeric manipulation. Do I need to drop down to shifting and masking numeric values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd like to elaborate on max taldykin's answer (that I have upvoted), which I think is over-complicated. There is no need for `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, `printf` or `Data.List`.

Here is my version:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Numeric (showHex)

prettyPrint :: B.ByteString -> String
prettyPrint = concat . map (flip showHex "") . B.unpack

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . prettyPrint . B.pack $ [102, 117, 110]
```

Comment: You'll mess up the result here since `showHex` will not pad to 2.

Comment: @Peaker is right, this solution is incorrect.  It cuts off any leading zeros. crockeea's answer at the bottom is correct.

Answer (score 17):

You can now use [`Data.ByteString.Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html). To print a `ByteString` to its hex equivalent (with two hex digits per byte, in the right order, and efficiently), simply use:

```
toLazyByteString . byteStringHex
```

or

```
toLazyByteString . lazyByteStringHex
```

depending on which flavor of `ByteString` you have as input.

Answer (score 4):

Somethig like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Text.Printf
import Data.List
import Numeric

hex = foldr showHex "" . B.unpack
list = printf "[%s]" . concat . intersperse "," . map show
```

Test:

```
> let x = B.pack [102,117,110]
> list . hex $ x
"['6','6','7','5','6','e']"
```

**Upd** Oh, there is a stupid memory leak: of course you should replace `foldr` with `foldl'` (because laziness is not required here):

```
hex = foldl' (flip showHex) "" . B.unpack
```

Comment: Of course the `foldl'` version prints the the bytes in reverse order, "little-endian" style.

Answer (score 3):

You have `["1","7e"]` :: [String]
`concat ["1", "7e"]` is `"17e" :: String` which is equal to [Char] and equal to `['1','7','e'] :: [Char]`.

Than you may split that String into pieces:

```
> Data.List.Split.splitEvery 1 . concat $ ["1", "7e"]
["1","7","e"]
it :: [[Char]]
```

Comment: `Data.List.Split.splitEvery 1` == `map (:[])`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a regular hex en/decoding of ByteStrings, you can use the memory package. They call the hex encoding Base16.

```
>>> let input = "Is 3 > 2?" :: ByteString
>>> let convertedTo base = convertToBase base input :: ByteString
>>> convertedTo Base16
"49732033203e20323f"
```

Full documentation: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.18.0/docs/Data-ByteArray-Encoding.html#t:Base